# intellij idea checkout error: doenst show "svn checkout options" dialog?

Tags: intellij-idea, svn

for my university i have to hand in some assignments. I use the newest version of intellij 2019.3 an a macbook. Now i have some problems with the subversion. When I want to checkout the repository, there is no "svn checkout opions" dialog. I attached a picture which dialog it doesn't show.
Thx for your help guys.

[image: SVN Checkout Options]

Answer (score 0):

The "Checkout Dialog" has been redesigned and now you can find it under **VCS | Get From Version Control**.
At the top part of a dialog please click on the drop-down list and pick Subversion.